# Get hostname from only its cname record

Tags: dns, reverse-dns

I have just the cname record `san.vitacost.com.edgekey.net` when I dig `www.vitacost.com`

This is the full dig result-

```
www.vitacost.com.   90  IN  CNAME   san.vitacost.com.edgekey.net.
san.vitacost.com.edgekey.net. 161 IN    CNAME   e35112.dsca.akamaiedge.net.
e35112.dsca.akamaiedge.net. 20  IN  A   23.200.156.78
e35112.dsca.akamaiedge.net. 20  IN  A   23.200.156.79
```

How can I get `www.vitacost.com` by only using `san.vitacost.com.edgekey.net`

I tried searching for reverse DNS lookup but did not find any solution for this,

Plese help